# Closing a Modal Box on ID Change

Tags: jquery, forms, modal-dialog, form-submit, simplemodal

I'm using the SimpleModal by Eric Martin (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) at www.1tryten.com/checkout.php. The code for loading is simply:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#CheckoutStepAccountDetails').modal();

});
```

This loads a form with 2 submit options, once the form has been submitted the class .ExpressCheckoutBlockCompleted is added to the div#CheckoutStepAccountDetails.  At this time I need the Modal to disappear.  I've tried adding the simplemodal-close class to the submit button, but then it simply closes the modal without submitting the form.  Does anyone know how I could make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben,
I doubdt that just adding a class to your div will let you disappear the modal.

I don't use that plugin but I use own custom code for my simple modal.

This is how I control when and how to control the modal to close:

```
//modal has a close button with id=modalclose. when it is clicked, I hide the modal mask
//this will close modal only if close button is clicked
$("#dialog #modalclose").click(function (e) { 
  $('#mask, .window').hide(); 
});

//if I want to close the modal by outside click on the mask
$("#mask").click(function (e) { 
  $('#mask, .window').hide(); 
});
```

So for your case you need to add this type of call once the form is submitted
If you have a callback function available upon the form is submitted, you can add the code to hide the modal inside that call back function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. would you be able to share a link with me so I can see how it works on your site?

Comment: As I said, I don't use that plugin. I use direct class and css. But I know how the modal pieces work in my code. Of course the plugin is more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, contrary to what Projapati said, adding a class of `simplemodal-close` to an element inside the modal will, in fact, cause the dialog to close when clicked.

Based on what you've provided, all you should need to do is the following:

```
//if I want to close the modal by outside click on the mask
$("#mask").click(function (e) { 
  $.modal.close(); 
});
```

Sorry I wasn't able to respond to this earlier, I was on vacation ;)